# How to remove comment from the begining of the file/string with php

Tags: php, regex

I have several text files, included in my code programatically. I need a regular expression, to be able to catch and remove the content of the comments from the catched string. (The comment contains )

The code where I catch the content of the file is:

```
ob_start();
include($file);
$c = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

An example content of the $file is as follows:

```
//Comment here
//Second line
//All the comment lines are optional
<p>Html content here</p>
<?php echo "Php content may also exists!"; ?>
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: And perhaps, `<?php echo "More text // to follow!"; ?> // Fourth comment`?

Comment: yes, there may be comment in the php code too, but only the comments from the begining of the scring should be removed.

Comment: What about you change $file to use valid PHP comments ? For example `<? // Comment here ?>`

Comment: unfortunatelly i cannot change that, the format of the file is given

Comment: Then just read the file line by line and if a trimmed line starts with `//` do not output it. No need in regex.

Comment: but I need to catch the content of the file, and also execute the php code from there. Can I use eval combined with the ob functions? I mean, will the ob functions catch the buffer from an eval?

Comment: Change the content of the file, this is really the only sane answer. If you can't, you need to process the content of `$c`, either line by line or with a multi-line regexp (fairly straightforward). But this is a bad idea. You should really just change the content of the file.

Comment: Well, perhaps, it is really easier with a regex. Try [`$c = preg_replace('~^\s*//.*$\s*~m', '', $c)`](https://ideone.com/IEx6Ge).

Comment: Could you move your comment to an answer, please, to be able to mark as final solution?

Comment: Done, but you should consider all the comments above when using my workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of solving this - *if the included files are not large* - is to use a  regex with a multiline flag/modifier that will match all lines starting with `//`.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/fork/IEx6Ge):

```
$re = '~^\s*//.*$\s*~m'; 
$str = "//Comment here\n//Second line\n//All the comment lines are optional\n<p>Html content here</p>\n<?php echo \"Php content may also exists!\"; ?>"; 
echo preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of a *line* (as we are  using a `/m` modifier)
- `\s*` - optional whitespace (0 or more occurrences)
- `//` - two forward slashes
- `.*` - any zero or more characters other than a newline
- `$` - end of *line* (as we are  using a `/m` modifier)
- `\s*` - optional whitespace (to trim the linebreaks).

Comment: Thank you! Also, what amount of kb you mean by not large?

Comment: Actually, I do not know since I mostly code in C#. In C#, I get memory issues with strings of more than 30MB.

Comment: Oh, I dont have such a big files. I dont think I will have files bigger than 500kb. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove only the comments until the actual code begins you need a state machine (the regex solution is more compact but removes the line comments anywhere):

```
$c = "//Comment here\n//Second line\n//All the comment lines are optional\n<p>Html content here</p>\n<?php echo \"Php content may also exists!\"; ?>";

$output = "";
$stripComments = true;
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $c) as $line) {
  if ( $stripComments ) {
    if ( preg_match("~^\s*//~",$line) )
      continue;
    else {
      $stripComments = false;
      $output .= $line."\n";
    }
  }
  else
    $output .= $line."\n";
}
echo "$output";
```

Comment: @stribizhev already gave me the working answer, but I really appreciate your answer too. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Zoli: thank you for your appreciation, if you know the comments are only above the code the regex solution is ok